# Security issues with Wordnik API AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, security, crossdomain.xml

I'm making an online game, that uses Wordnik API AS3 to fetch word definitions. Everything works fine when i'm testing localy (sandboxType: localTrusted). But when I upload my .swf (sandboxType: remote or localWithNetwork) I get Wordnik API response "Security error accessing url".

I've set "useNetworkServices" to true.

I'm doing:

```
Security.allowDomain("api.wordnik.com");
Security.loadPolicyFile("api.wordnik.com/crossdomain.xml");
```

It could be some issue with crossdomain.xml. When testing in localTrusted I get the debug message "api.wordnik.com does not specify meta-rule. using default meta-rule 'master-only'". I get similar message for Google Interactive Media Ads, but it defaults to 'by-content-type'. Google IMA works when uploaded, Wordnik doesn't.

I'm not even sure if the problem is on my side.

Helpful answer would provide a working solution for the security issue, or point to any application using Wordnik AS3 API online - maybe its developers could help.

:)

Comment: Don't you need to specify http:// in the URL to load the crossdomain.xml file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but adding it doesn't solve the issue.